# Number filter filters number down to two decimals, but does not display it that way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is what I see:

[image]

The value is set at `160.90`, but displays as `160.8999999999` etc.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="imprint.total" 
    value="{{imprint.total | number:2}}" readonly>
```

It goes through filtering of certain inputs to get that total, but essentially it's just a price multiplied to quantity.

Comment: ng-model will override value. You will have to use parsers/formatters. If it is readonly you could just remove ng-model, `<input class="form-control" 
    value="{{imprint | number:2}}" readonly>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value in the value attribute will be overridden by `ng-model` directive when it sets the viewvalue as it renders. You have a readonly textbox you could just as well remove the ng-model from it.

```
<input class="form-control" 
       value="{{imprint.total | number:2}}" readonly>
```

With `ng-model` and to format live data entry you would need to create a directive and use [parsers/formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) to format the value.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('format', ['numberFilter',
  function(numberFilter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
        var decPlaces = attr.format || 2;

        function formatter(value) {

          if (value) {
            return numberFilter(value, decPlaces);
          }
        }

        ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);

      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="imprint=164.899999">
  <input class="form-control" value="{{imprint | number:2}}" readonly>

  <input class="form-control" ng-model="imprint" format="2" readonly>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use of custom filter , using toFixed method will restricts the No. of decimal values ,

```
App.filter('twoDecimal',function(input, scope){

return function(){

   return input.toFixed(2);

  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { name: ''};
});
app.directive('twoDecimal', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {debugger
        return Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
      });
      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="set to '12.23453'" ng-click="data.name='12.23453'"/>
    <input type="button" value="set to '34.3333'" ng-click="data.name='34.3333'"/>
    <input two-decimal ng-model="data.name" />
    <pre>model is: {{data.name}}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```