# Display number always with 2 decimal places in <input>

Tags: angularjs

I have a float value for the ng-model that I would like to always display with 2 decimal places in the `<input>`:

```
<input ng-model="myNumb" step ="0.01" type="number">
```

This works for most case when "myNumb" has decimal. But it will not force display of the 2  decimal places if "myNumb" has less than 2 decimal places (3.2), or an integer(30)
How can I force a display of 2 decimal place in the `<input>` field

Comment: since the <input> has type="number", if i do toFixed(2) it will throw an error. :(

Answer (score 89):

[AngularJS - Input number with 2 decimal places](http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/) it could help...
 Filtering:

> 3. Set the regular expression to validate the input using ng-pattern. Here I want to accept only numbers with a maximum of 2 decimal places and with a dot separator.

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal | number : 2" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
```

Reading forward this was pointed on the next answer [ng-model="myDecimal | number : 2"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

Comment: Done, sorry I didn't consider that because I thought that having it in context was better, but then again, you are right.

Comment: that displays "1" instead of "1.00"

Comment: That doesn't work. It checks that the input has no more than 2 decimals, but doesn't change the displayed number to display the 2 decimals (even if those are 0)

Comment: use this directive var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { name: ''};
});
app.directive('changecase', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {debugger
        return Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
      });
      
    }
  }
});

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? And as @jcc pointed out below, you can't use filters in ng-model. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Remove type="number"

Comment: It's been mentioned elsewhere, but this doesn't work because an `input` of type `number` expects a `Number` as it's value, but the angular `number` filter returns a `String`.  Suggesting to make the `input` type `text` is really just sidestepping the issue.

Comment: ngModel with myDecimal | number: 2 doesn't work. Error! Expression 'myDecimal | number: 2' is non-assignable. Element: <input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal | number: 2">

Answer (score 87):

If you are using Angular 2 (apparently it also works for Angular 4 too), you can use the following to round to two decimal places`{{ exampleNumber | number : '1.2-2' }}`, as in:

```
<ion-input value="{{ exampleNumber | number : '1.2-2' }}"></ion-input>
```

---

**BREAKDOWN**

`'1.2-2'` means `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`:

- A minimum of 1 digit will be shown before decimal point
- It will show at least 2 digits after decimal point
- But not more than 2 digits

Credit due [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456114/angular-2-pipe-limit-to-2-decimal-places) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477970/what-are-the-parameters-for-the-number-pipe-angular-2)

Answer (score 54):

> ```
> {{value | number : fractionSize}}
> ```

like `{{12.52311 | number : 2}}`

so this will print `12.52`

Comment: It's for angular.js, which is an older version of Angular

Answer (score 43):

Simply use the number pipe like so :

`{{ numberValue | number : '.2-2'}}`

The pipe above works as follows :

- Show at-least 1 integer digit before decimal point, set by default
- Show not less 2 integer digits after the decimal point
- Show not more than 2 integer digits after the decimal point

Answer (score 29):

Did you try using the filter

```
<input ng-model='val | number: 2'>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: this actually won't work, because i am using <input type="number"> this will throw an error. and i cannot not use a type="number" in this case

Comment: You can't do this in Angular, ng-model only accepts assignable expressions... https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign

Comment: Please see the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760310/number-filter-filters-number-down-to-two-decimals-but-does-not-display-it-that/42688335#42688335

Comment: in ng-model you can't use filter it's showing non-assign error

Answer (score 5):

Another shorthand to (@maudulus's answer) to remove `{maxFractionDigits}` since it's optional.

You can use `{{numberExample | number : '1.2'}}`

Answer (score 3):

best way to Round off number to decimal places is that

```
a=parseFloat(Math.round(numbertobeRound*10^decimalplaces)/10^decimalplaces);
```

for Example ;

```
numbertobeRound=58.8965896589;
```

if you want 58.90

decimalplaces is 2

```
a=parseFloat(Math.round(58.8965896589*10^2)/10^2);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please review your answer and edit it. Please take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
(Math.round(2.782061 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

This will convert that into Two decimal places:

For example: 2.782061 ---> 2.78 two decimal Places

Answer (score -1):

Use currency filter with empty symbol ($)

```
{{val | currency:''}}
```

Comment: this actually won't work, because i am using <input type="number"> this will throw an error. and i cannot not use a type="number" in this case