# Limit to 2 decimal places with a simple pipe

Tags: angular, pipe, decimal

I have found an example which limits a number to 2 decimal places AND turns the figure into a currency amount- eg £2.55.

```
{{ number | currency : 'GBP' : true : '1.2-2'}}
```

Is there a simple pipe which does the same without applying a currency?

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Currency pipe uses the [`number`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1608d91728af707d9740756a80e78cfb1148dd5a/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L82) one internally for number formatting. So you can use it like this:

```html
{{ number | number : '1.2-2'}}
```

Comment: [refer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html) for details regarding using number pipe

Comment: This was helpful in understanding why `1.2-2` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477970/what-are-the-parameters-for-the-number-pipe-angular-2

Comment: How do I restrict it to have always maximum 3 digits and 2 decimals?

Comment: For future readers, `{{ x | number : '1.2'}}` is also valid and means the same thing.

Comment: mehaase, is not the same. For example if you have 5.6 and 5.6789 the output will be 5.60 and 5.6789. So, the first parameter is the min and the second is the number of maximum digits.

Comment: How to use Pipe to transform a number to 1 decimal place and without roundup. Ex: 345.678 => 345.6

Comment: @Brian Implement custom pipe that maybe uses number internally and slices to necessary length.

Answer (score 15):

It's Works

```
.ts -> pi = 3.1415

.html -> {{ pi | number : '1.0-2' }}

Ouput -> 3.14
```

1. if it has a decimal it only shows one
2. if it has two decimals it shows both

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8g2pt?file=src/app/app.component.html

this works for me!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

Well now will be different after angular 5:

```
{{ number | currency :'GBP':'symbol':'1.2-2' }}
```

Comment: He wants to show value without currency symbol so DecimalPipe
will work for him.

Answer (score 7):

> Simple solution

```
{{ orderTotal | number : '1.2-2'}}

//output like this

// public orderTotal = 220.45892221

//   {{ orderTotal | number : '1.2-2'}} 

// final Output
//  220.45
```