# What are the parameters for the number Pipe - Angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, decimal

I have used the number pipe below to limit numbers to two decimal places.

```
{{ exampleNumber | number : '1.2-2' }}
```

I was wondering what the logic behind '1.2-2' was? I have played around with these trying to achieve a pipe which filters to zero decimal places but to no avail.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-class.html

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/built-in-pipes-angular/

Comment: This only works with Angular 2

Answer (score 390, accepted):

The parameter has this syntax:

[`{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

So your example of `'1.2-2'` means:

- A minimum of 1 digit will be shown before decimal point
- It will show at least 2 digits after decimal point
- But not more than 2 digits

Comment: This also unfortunately rounds the number, and even worse, there's no word about it in the documentation

Comment: @Blauhirn I have the same problem, was there an easy fix or should I create my own pipe?

Comment: @phil294 I know your comment is old, but, now there is a description about rounding numbers. https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: If minFractionDigits is greater than 0, then getting error.                                             The minimum number of digits after fraction (2) is higher than the maximum (0).' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Answer (score 22):

1. Regarding your first question.The pipe works as follows:

   `numberValue | number: {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`

   - minIntegerDigits: Minimum number of integer digits to show before decimal point,set to 1by default
   - minFractionDigits: Minimum number of integer digits to show after the decimal point
   - maxFractionDigits: Maximum number of integer digits to show after the decimal point

2.Regarding your second question, Filter to zero decimal places as follows:

```
{{ numberValue | number: '1.0-0' }}
```

For further reading, checkout the following [blog](https://medium.com/@mwiza/getting-started-with-angular-decimal-pipe-b987b27b5e19)

Answer (score 10):

From the  **[`DOCS`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)**

> Formats a number as text. Group sizing and separator and other
>   locale-specific configurations are based on the active locale.

**SYNTAX:**

**`number_expression | number[:digitInfo[:locale]]`**

where **`expression`** is a number:

**`digitInfo`** is a string which has a following format:

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

- minIntegerDigits is the minimum number of integer digits to use.Defaults to 1
- minFractionDigits is the minimum number of digits
- after fraction. Defaults to 0. maxFractionDigits is the maximum
  number of digits after fraction. Defaults to 3.
- locale is a string defining the locale to use (uses the current LOCALE_ID by default)

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/TtXzN3hFrnqxV9vwSihA?p=preview)**

Answer (score 5):

'0.0-0' will give you round formatted number with ','

100000.2 -> 100,000

very cool

Answer (score 2):

'1.0-0' will give you 
zero decimal places i.e. no decimals.
e.g.$500

Comment: I am trying to format a number like 114.5 to display as 114 but when I use '1.0-0' it displays '115' anybody know why?

Comment: It's because angular rounds the value and gives 115 for 114.5.

Comment: Why the downvotes? this works and answers the question of how to filter to zero decimal places. Thanks @alchibaucha solved my problem precisely.