# format a number with double precision angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I need to load a number in input form but there is some problem when I format the number. In details the number can be :

```
1.99
15.00
230.88
2,999.00
etc
```

I use this code:

```
 [ngModel]="price |  number : '1.2-2' "
```

but it gives me this warning:

```
The specified value "1,333.00" is not a valid number.
```

I use Angular 6. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Tried removing the comma character?

Comment: @ShubhamJain it is not work the same, because when I put the number after I finish to write in input field, it disappear and it gives me the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first** problem is caused by the comma. For any other reason **another** problem is that `number : '1.2-2'` does not take values larger 3 digits before comma.

I have create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdzdiw) to show a possible solution:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="price | toNumber "/>
```

Use a custom pipe to replace the `,` and to ensure `number : '1.2-2'` still valid. You can extend it by your need to solve any problem.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toNumber'
})
export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string):any {
    let retNumber = parseFloat(parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2))
    return isNaN(retNumber) ? 0 : retNumber;
  }
}
```

**Advantage of custom pipe solution:** You can customize your behavior. `number : '1.2-2'` unfortunately rounds the number, and even worse, there's no word about it in the documentation (found in the comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38478060/3623608)