# Using Firebase reauthenticate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'll appreciate assistance with how to reauthenticate a user in Firebase. I wonder if it makes any sense adding all these great features if the documentation doesn't explain how to use it:

Currently, this is what I'm trying, and it ain't working. Errors as `cannot read property 'credential' of undefined`

In constructor:

```
  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: any) {
    this.auth = firebaseApp.auth();
    console.log(this.auth);
  }
```

then the function

```
changePassword(passwordData) {
    if(passwordData.valid) {
      console.log(passwordData.value);
      // let us reauthenticate first irrespective of how long
      // user's been logged in!

      const user = this.auth.currentUser;
      const credential = this.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, passwordData.value.oldpassword);
      console.log(credential);
      this.auth.reauthenticate(credential)
        .then((_) => {
          console.log('User reauthenticated');
          this.auth.updatePassword(passwordData.value.newpassword)
            .then((_) => {
              console.log('Password changed');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I'm running into the same issues.

Comment: @MK_Dev You tried Frank's answer? You should call the reauthenticate on the user, not the auth. Maybe it now would work, because it never did for me.

Comment: actually, it did work. I was having the same issue where EmailAuthProvider was undefined. What I had to do was "cast" firebase to any:
var fb: any = firebase;
var credential = fb.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

Comment: Their documentation are awful in places. You'd think with their expertise, knowledge, experience and manpower that they would have amazing documentation :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `reauthenticate()` method is called on a [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User), not on [firebase.auth.Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) itself.

```
var user = firebase.app.auth().currentUser;
var credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential('puf@firebaseui.com', 'firebase');
user.reauthenticate(credentials);
```

---

**Update (July 2017)**:

There are some breaking change in the 4.0 version of the Firebase Web SDK. From the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.0.0):

> BREAKING: `firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticate` has been removed in favor of [`firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticateWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithCredential).

As far as I can tell the `reauthenticateWithCredential`is a drop-in replacement for the old method.

Comment: Anything difference between your code and mine? I have widely open eyes trying to figure out how different your code is from mine, but I can't.

Comment: You call `this.auth.reauthenticate`, where `this` seems to refer to `firebase.auth()`. I call `user.reauthenticate` on the user.

Comment: Okay, `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider` gives me an undefined. In full, if I do this: `firebaseApp.auth.EmailAuthProvider`, I get an undefined. Is the `FirebaseApp` actually exposing everything Firebase?

Comment: Did a bit of reading about the `FirebaseApp`, and it doesn't look as mapping entirely to the native SDK `FirebaseApp`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I have no idea what you're seeing there. I ran the code snippet I shared in a browser and it re-authenticates the user. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin/jsfiddle?

Comment: Please see the code here - https://github.com/seanmavley/AngularFire2-Authentication/blob/master/app/dashboard/child.component.ts

Comment: Updated answer here, since apparently the moderator won't let me answer on this question (note that reauthenticate is deprecated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513413/angular-how-to-display-number-always-with-2-decimal-places-in-input/44124785#44124785

Comment: UPDATE 2023: The link to `firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticateWithCredential` leads to a 404 page. For Firebase v8 docs, go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential). For Firebase v9, apparently you need to `import { reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";`, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186075/error-with-reauthenticatewithcredential-get-error-typeerror-credential-getreau?rq=3).

Comment: Just found the section in the official docs for Firebase v9: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that enabled users to (a) reauthenticate in Firebase and (b) change their passwords after reauthenticating for me. I researched for about an hour while writing this, so hopefully it saves someone a minute.

Wrote in VueJS:

```
changePassword() {
            let self = this; // i use "self" to get around scope issues
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
                this.$store.state.userId, // references the user's email address
                this.oldPassword
            );

            user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
                .then(function() {
                    // User re-authenticated.
                    user.updatePassword(self.newPassword) 
                        .then(function() {
                            console.log("Password update successful!");
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(
                                "An error occurred while changing the password:",
                                error
                            );
                        });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Some kinda bug: ", error);
                    // An error happened.
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight changes as of May 2019, see more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_600_-_may_7_2019). Code is as follows:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, password);

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
return user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `changeEmail("new email","password")` in `onPressed` directly to update the user email with no reauthentication required error

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    changeEmail(_emailController.text, _passwordController.text);
  }              

 Future<void> changeEmail(String email, String password) async {
   User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  print(email);
  print(password);
  try {
    try {
      var authResult = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(
        EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
          email: user.email,
          password: password,
        ),
      );
      user.updateEmail(email).then((_) {
        print("Succesfull changed email");
        _backthrow();
      }).catchError((error) {
        showAlertDialog(context, error.message);
        print("email can't be changed" + error.toString());
      });
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      print("2");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
    showAlertDialog(context, e.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I re-authenticate a user in Firebase:

```
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider, reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth()

const reauthenticateUser = async (email, password) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  try {
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential)
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert("Error", "The email or password is incorrect. Please try again.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hers a full example how to reauthenticate with Firebase

```
var pass = "abcdefg";
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, pass);

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
    console.log("Its good!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2021:** If you use Firebase JS API 9.x (the tree shakable version) this is the most recent way:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/reauth

**With credentials**

```js
import { getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

// todo for you: prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
const credential = promptForCredentials();

reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // ...
});
```

**With popup**

```js
import { getAuth, reauthenticateWithPopup, OAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
// todo for you: change to appropriate provider
const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');

reauthenticateWithPopup(auth.currentUser, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting that re-authentication error `auth/requires-recent-login` when saving the primary email.
I couldn't figure out how to implement that poorly documented `reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)` method, so, I simply logged-out the user and redirected to login page. It's a hack but It works like charm!

```
firebase.auth().signOut();
```