# Firebase auth reauthenticate is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting a :

> Uncaught TypeError: user.reauthenticate is not a function

with this code below.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email,'foo');

console.log(user) // the currentUser object
console.log(user.reauthenticate) // undefined    

user.reauthenticate(credentials)
    .then(() => {
        // Do something
    }, err => console.log(error));
```

I just followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) and [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39876543/2889614) by [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: In the accepted answer I see this `var user = firebase.app.auth().currentUser;` whereas you have `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;`.

Comment: Can you try `user.reauthenticateWithCredential`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithCredential

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen `user. reauthenticateWithCredential` worked. I found it yesterday on under the `user` object. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

We made a breaking change in the 4.0 version of the Firebase Web SDK. From the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.0.0):

> BREAKING: `firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticate` has been removed in favor of [`firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticateWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithCredential).

As far as I can tell the `reauthenticateWithCredential`is a drop-in replacement for the old method.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Somehow this got missed in the documentation guides. The fix for that is in flight.

Comment: UPDATE 2023: The link to `firebase.User.prototype.reauthenticateWithCredential` leads to a 404 page. For Firebase v8 docs, go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential). For Firebase v9, apparently you need to `import { reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";`, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186075/error-with-reauthenticatewithcredential-get-error-typeerror-credential-getreau?rq=3).