# error with reauthenticateWithCredential get error TypeError: credential._getReauthenticationResolver is not a function (firebase 9)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am learning firebase. now want to change password with reauthenticateWithCredential(). but get error like this.

> TypeError: credential._getReauthenticationResolver is not a function

this the code:

```
import { getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

const credential = signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, this.oldPassword);
reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
// User re-authenticated.
 console.log(credential)
}).catch((error) => {
 console.log(error)
});
```

can anyone point out where the error is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe still not quite right, but give this a try :

```
import {
  getAuth,
  reauthenticateWithCredential,
  EmailAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

try {
 const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  user.email,
  this.oldPassword
 );
 reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
  // User re-authenticated.
  // Code...
 });
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error.message);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This works, but user.multiFactor isn't in the user object. I know this is a slightly different topic of MFA, but any ideas why that variable would not exist when I expect it to?

Comment: I got the exact same error, this solved it for me! Thanks