# Angular 6 show the zero in 1.0 if the type is number

Tags: angular, typescript

In my code I have something like this here:

```
var myNumber: number = 1.0;
```

However angular automatically removes the zero in my respective form. I could make it a string but that seems like an odd solution.

How can I tell Angular that it should also display the zero and not remove it?

Comment: that's exactly how javascript works (there is only one `number` type). To see this open your developer JS console with F12 and just write `console.log(1.0)`. You want to format the display of your number. What I mean by my comment, is that any solution, would it be Angular specific or general Javascript would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular how to display number always with 2 decimal places in <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513413/angular-how-to-display-number-always-with-2-decimal-places-in-input)

Comment: But that function is still there: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski you are right. I removed my comment (though I'm uncomfortable voting for this duplicate target anyway)

Comment: You can use DecimalPipe as said above https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: can't you use `{{myNumber.toFixed(1)}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

```
{{myNumber | number : '1.1-1'}}
```

Parameters of pipe explained [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#parameters) in docs

> Decimal representation options, specified by a string in the following
> format: {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}.
>
> 1. minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the    decimal point. Default is 1.
> 2. minFractionDigits: The minimum number of digits after the decimal
>    point. Default is 0.
> 3. maxFractionDigits: The maximum number of digits after the decimal
>    point. Default is 3.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). Add inside your template kind of that here:

```
{{ value_expression | number }}
```

This will cause to display the number as it is definde.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) as follows:

```
{{ myNumber | number:'1.1-1' }}
```

This says:

Make sure there is at least 1 (the 1st one) number before the decimal place and

Between 1 (the 2nd one) and 1 (the 3rd one) numbers after the decimal place