# Add 2 decimals to variable type number

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to format one variable to always have 2 decimals, but I can't get how to do it for the following reason - it always either removes the 0 at the end or says:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

The `viewer_gain` variable is type number, so that creates the issue, I can have a string with 2 decimals, but not number ...

This is what I am doing:

```
setCompensation() {
      // set these variables to string, to use toFixed(2)
      let value: string;
      let zero: string;
      if (isNaN(this.campaignModel.per_view_pay) || !this.compensateV) {

          // since toFixed is converting to string, i am trying to parseFloat later.
          zero = (0).toFixed(2); 

          // removes the 0 at the end here
          this.campaignModel.viewer_gain = parseFloat(zero);
      } else {

          // since toFixed is converting to string, i am trying to parseFloat later.
          value = (this.campaignModel.per_view_pay / 2).toFixed(2);

          // removes the 0 at the end here
          this.campaignModel.viewer_gain = parseFloat(value);
      }
    }
```

Anyone done this in another way?

Comment: Don't do the parseFloat on the display string

Comment: @mplungjan but if I don't do that, I get the error for string and number.

Comment: which line error populate?

Comment: Do not do a toFixed on something you want to calculate with and do not do a parseFloat on something you want to display - you do not NEED 2 decimals in the internal calculations

Comment: How can I display 2 decimals when I do the calculation? @mplungjan

Comment: I do not see any code that displays any value. I only see calculations - you need to use the toFixed in the code that actually displays the value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513413/angular-how-to-display-number-always-with-2-decimal-places-in-input