# How to set mask for decimal values in angular?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, masking

I want to set masking for decimal values with range

I have formControl (Using ReactiveForms) of amount as
Typescript code

```
'Amount': [0, Validators.max(999999999.99)]
```

HTML code

```
<input currencyMask [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: ',', decimal: '.', align: '' }" type="text" formControlName="Amount">
```

Currently I am using 'currencyMask', when I am typing value in amount it takes value from right side (means is starts taking value after '.' For eg. If I type '53' it takes value as '0.53'),
but I want to take take value from left side (eg. '53.00')

How can I do that or else any other option is available?Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular how to display number always with 2 decimal places in <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513413/angular-how-to-display-number-always-with-2-decimal-places-in-input)

Comment: this can help you : https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#description